# What are the three non-isomorphic 2-dimensional algebras over $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

> What are the three non-isomorphic $2$-dimensional algebras over $\mathbb{R}$?

Am I right in thinking they are
$\lbrace x+iy: x,y\in\mathbb{R},\ i^{2}=-1\rbrace$,
$\lbrace x+jy: x,y\in\mathbb{R},\ j^{2}=1\rbrace$ and
$\lbrace x+\varepsilon y: x,y\in\mathbb{R},\ \varepsilon^{2}=0\rbrace$?

Comment: Another way to write what you have above that might be a bit more "uniform" is $\mathbb{R}[x]/((x+1)(x-1)), \mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1), \mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2)$.

Comment: @Quasicoherent Or even $\mathbb R[x]/(x^2-1)$, $\mathbb R[x]/(x^2+0)$, $\mathbb R[x]/(x^2+1)$.

Comment: @OscarCunningham Sure, I just wanted to emphasize the behavior of the polynomials: two distinct factors, irreducible, or one repeated factor.  It's analogous to primes being split, inert, or ramified in an extension.  But the way you've written it does look more like the OP.

Answer (score 8):

You're right, these are in fact the three isomorphism classes of two-dimensional commutative real algebras.

Let $A$ be a real two-dimensional algebra.

Let $x \in A \setminus \mathbb{R}$. Then, the set $1,x,x^2$ must be linearly dependent, so we have a non-trivial equation of the form $\lambda_1x^2+\lambda_2x+\lambda_3=0$ Note that $\lambda_1 \neq 0$, as $1,x$ is linearly independent, as the subspace generated by it properly contains $\mathbb{R}$, so must be two-dimensional, i.e. $A$. So after divison by $\lambda_1$, we may assume that $\lambda_1 = 1$.
Now we complete the square and get $0=x^2+\lambda_2x+\lambda_3 = (x+\frac{\lambda_2}{2})^2+\lambda_3-\frac{\lambda_2^2}{4}$
Now take $v = x + \frac{\lambda_2}{2}$, then the last equation shows that $v^2 \in \mathbb{R}$ . Now $A$ is spanned by $1,v$ (as the subspace generated by $1,v$ properly contains $\mathbb{R}$, so it is two-dimensional). If $v^2=0$, then clearly we have $A \cong \lbrace x+\varepsilon y: x,y\in\mathbb{R}, \varepsilon^{2}=0\rbrace$
if $v^2 \neq 0$, normalize $v$ by setting $u= \frac{v}{\sqrt{|v^2|}}$, now $u^2= \pm 1$ and we have $A \cong \lbrace x+iy: x,y\in\mathbb{R}, i^{2}=1\rbrace$, if $u^2=1$ and $A \cong \lbrace x+jy: x,y\in\mathbb{R}, j^{2}=-1\rbrace$ if $u^2=-1$

This shows that any two-dimensional real algebra is isomorphic to one of these three. To show that there are no isomorphisms among them, note that $\lbrace x+jy: x,y\in\mathbb{R}, j^{2}=-1\rbrace \cong \mathbb C$ is a field, so it contains neither non-trivial idempotents nor non-trivial nilpotents. And note that $ \lbrace x+\varepsilon y: x,y\in\mathbb{R}, \varepsilon^{2}=0\rbrace \cong \mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2)$ is a local ring with maximal ideal $(\varepsilon)$, so it does not contain non-trivial idempotents either, whereas $\lbrace x+iy: x,y\in\mathbb{R}, i^{2}=1\rbrace \cong \mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2-1) \cong \mathbb{R}[x]/(x-1) \times \mathbb{R}[x]/(x+1) \cong \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ does contain non-trivial idempotents.