# What are the various two-dimensional algebras over $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

The complex numbers can be given a matrix representation:
$$a+bi \cong \begin{pmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{pmatrix}$$
A *split* complex number can be given a matrix representation:
$$c+dj \cong \begin{pmatrix} c & d \\ d & c \end{pmatrix}$$
Finally, a *dual* number can be given a matrix representation:
$$f+g\epsilon \cong \begin{pmatrix} f & g \\ 0 & f \end{pmatrix}$$

All of these can be viewed as two-dimensional algebras over the real numbers. Are these the only possible algebras, up to isomorphism?

They can also be viewed as “two-parameter” Lie groups. Are there any other possible two-parameter Lie groups that are subgroups of the $2 \times 2$ real matrices?

Comment: We can also give dual numbers a matrix representation in a similar way, with $$a + b\varepsilon \cong \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & a \end{pmatrix}$$ Up to isomorphism, I believe these three are the only two-dimensional algebras over the reals. Is it possible that their matrix representations are similarly the only three two-parameter rings up to isomorphism?

Comment: Define "two-parameter continuous linear ring".

Comment: I downvoted until you clarify what you are looking for. If it is two-dimensional (associative, unital) algebras over $\mathbb R$, then look at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2217906/96384, or better yet at the generalization to arbitrary ground fields in the answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3210183/96384 (which is basically identical to the one by Anne Bauval here).

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I have clarified.